# Python 3 - Regular Expressions - Matching Words in dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I was wondering how I would approach trying to see if the word I have is in the english dictionary. I have a dictionary from a word file that I downloaded, and a word that I wanna see if its close to any word in the english dictionary. So I have the word that gets changed so for example if the word is some gibberish like 'EDBGZH' and pairs = {'ED':'TE', 'BG':'ST'} I will get a newWord = 'TESTZH' and the word in the enlish dictionary it will match with will be TESTER. So I am wondering how I can write a regular expression to get a match.

```
for word in englishDictionary:
    re.match('.....', word) #Want it to print the words that it matches with. Sorry Im new to regular expressions and they're very confusing to me
```

I want the match to be with the letters that are changed, and the ones that are not changed to be the ones that get matched with the rest of the word.

Comment: TESTZH does not match TESTER. You'll have to be a bit more specific on the "matching" bit: do you want "closest match" (by edit distance perhaps), or a prefix match, or a match on the translated characters?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want a match on the parts that have been changed by the dictionary named pairs. So like the first four letters of the word are changed, like TESTZH then the ZH part isn't changed but since the first four letters are changed then it matches to TESTER because thats close.

Comment: Just convert the unchanged characters to `.` (the regex symbol for "any character"). That gives you the regex you want.

Comment: Okay, so I've managed to change the unchanged characters to a dot, but not I'm having troubles with the re.match(newWord, word) How can I check the match with the word being in a variable and print the match if it matches

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like this,

```
>>> s = 'EDBGZH'
>>> pairs = {'ED':'TE', 'BG':'ST'}
>>> for i in pairs:
        s = s.replace(i, pairs[i])


>>> print(s)
TESTZH
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a python's `dictionary`, I assume your keys are unique. Yet, you may have word like `EDEDBGZH`, so should we replace **all** the occurrences in the source word or not?

Anyway, I assume @AvinashRaj's answer is good enought, but I'm gonna extend it a bit.

Let us have a 'replaced' word, `TESTZH`. If you then want to find the **closest match** in the dictionary, you may want to search using some of  word distance functions. For example, [Levenshtein's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It sets some criteria for words *much like the other one*. So, for example, words `winter` and `linter` will be more close one to another than `winter` and `splinter` while being much more closer than `winter` and `python`.

Here's the code of Levenshtein's distance function:

```
def lev(s1, s2, l1 = None, l2 = None):
  if l1 == None:
    l1 = len(s1)

  if l2 == None:
    l2 = len(s2)

  if l1 == 0:
    return l2
  elif l2 == 0:
    return l1

  if (s1[l1 - 1] == s2[l2 - 1]):
    cost = 0
  else:
    cost = 1

  return min([
    lev(s1, s2, l1 - 1, l2) + 1, 
    lev(s1, s2, l1, l2 - 1) + 1,
    lev(s1, s2, l1 - 1, l2 - 1) + cost
  ])
```

And some samples:

```
print("lev(winter, linter) = %d" % lev('winter', 'linter'))
print("lev(winter, splinter) = %d" % lev('winter', 'splinter'))
print("lev(winter, python) = %d" % lev('winter', 'python'))

>>> lev(winter, linter) = 1
>>> lev(winter, splinter) = 3
>>> lev(winter, python) = 6
```

Here's the code to search in the dictionary using the Levenshtein's distance function:

```
dictionary = { 'winter': 'zima', 'spring': 'wiosna', 'summer': 'lato', 'autumn': 'jesień', 'Poland': 'Polska' }
search_for = 'wintr'
similars = { k: dictionary[k] for k in filter(lambda x: lev(x, search_for) <= 3, dictionary.keys()) }
```

And the sample run:

```
>>> words similar to `wintr`: {'winter': 'zima'}
```

Hope this helps!